# Print multiple empty lines without repeating \n

Tags: shell, newlines

`echo` is used to produce a new line in Linux.

`echo -e '\n'` 2 lines

`echo -e '\n\n'` 3 lines and so on.

e.g.

```
user@linux:~$ echo

user@linux:~$ echo -e '\n'


user@linux:~$ echo -e '\n\n'



user@linux:~$
```

Instead of typing `\n\n`, would it be possible to use something like `\n * 3`.

**Desired Output**

I know `echo -e '\n * 3'` won't produce 3 lines, but I hope you get what I mean.

```
user@linux:~$ echo -e '\n * 3' # <== I hope you get what I mean



user@linux:~$
```

Comment: `yes '' | head -n3`, `printf '%.0s\n' {1..3}`

Comment: `perl -e 'print "\n" x 3'`

Comment: @mosvy, thanks but getting error.

`head: invalid number of lines: ‘3,’`

Comment: @Kusalananda, yeah why not. Didn't think about this before. Thanks

Comment: The comma is not part of the command -- it's not even highlighted and it should show in a different font ;-) The `yes '' | head -n3`   and   `printf '%.0s\n' {1..3}` are 2 different commands, both doing the same thing.

Comment: @mosvy, my bad, you should answer it, I'll accept it as you're the 1st one responded to this question. All other answers are correct too, can't accept all of them.

Comment: You should accept icarus's answer, which is similar.

Comment: @mosvy, if you insist :)

Comment: @Sabrina Added some (:-)) alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @Isaac. I really appreciate it. All tested and working fine. Btw, `zsh` is missing the last quote.

Comment: Thanks @Sabrina , typo corrected :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a POSIX solution is required, use:

#### loop

Beside the obvious (and ugly looking) POSIX loop:

```
i=0; while [ "$((i+=1))" -le 7 ]; do echo; done
```

#### POSIX (portable)

There are other (shorter, not necessarily faster) solutions:

(1) Print spaces, convert to newlines.

```
printf '%*s' 30 | tr ' ' '\n'
```

(2) Or, to get 23 lines

```
seq 23 | tr -dc '\n'
```

(3) Using awk:

```
seq 23 | awk '{printf "\n"}'
```

(4) Assuming IFS is default

```
printf '%.0s\n' $(seq 23)
```

(5) `sed` appends one additional newline, for 23 newlines, use 22:

```
printf '%0*d' 22 | sed 'y/0/\n/'
```

(6) Some shells auto create all the lower numbered array elements.

```
zsh -c 'a[33]=1; printf "%.0s\n" "${a[@]}"'
```

(7) Get some NUL bytes

```
head -c 5 /dev/zero | tr '\0' '\n'
```

#### widely known

Those are beside the more widely known (and used) solutions:

(8) Use `head` counting:

```
yes '' | head -n 23
```

(9) **Not** POSIX. For some shells (ksh, bash, zsh at least):

```
printf '%.0s\n' {1..23}
```

#### other languages

And, of course, using (**non** POSIX) higher level languages:

(10) Perl

```
perl -e 'print "\n" x 23'
perl -E 'say "\n" x 22'
```

(11) PHP

```
php -r 'echo str_repeat( "\n" , 3 );'
```

(12) Python

```
python -c 'print("\n" * 3)'
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using bash or ksh93 or zsh then

```
printf '%.0s\n' {1..3}
```

will produce 3 newlines. The `{1..3}` expands to `1 2 3`, and then the `printf` outputs these as zero width strings followed by newline.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ yes "" | head -30
```

to get you 30 newlines.

Comment: `head -30` is not portable. Use `head -n30` or `sed 30q`.

Answer (score 1):

In case using python is an option, the following command behaves the way you want:

```
python -c 'print("\n" * 3)'
```